# SELECT 2 Identical databases to get 2 website orders on one list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect two databases into a mysql query and it's also great!

After that, I try to find data on the order in the correct database to get meta_value from it.

But it mixes meta_value $ first name and sometimes duplicates them on the rows.

If I just conect 1 database, they will come out as they should
Anybody can see what goes wrong?

Url to example: https:// http://kundeservice.coalsmile.com/test4.php

```
  <?php
$servername = "xxx";
 $username = "xxx";
 $password = "xxx";


  $v1 = "coalsmil_wp282";
  $v2 = "coalsmil_wp111";
  $v3 = "coalsmil_wp72";
  $v4 = "coalsmil_wp193";
  $v5 = "coalsmil_wp555";
  $v6 = "coalsmil_wp366";
  $v7 = "coalsmil_wp74";
  $v8 = "coalsmil_wp721";
  $v9 = "coalsmil_wp924";
  $v10 = "coalsmil_wp253";


      // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

  // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       }
      echo "Connected successfully";

   //Here I connect to both databases
    $query103 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `$v1`.`wpd2_posts` 
        where post_status='wc-processing' or post_status='wc-completed'
           or post_status='wc-failed' UNION
     SELECT * FROM `$v2`.`wpd2_posts` 
       where post_status='wc-processing' or post_status='wc-completed'
        or post_status='wc-failed' order by post_date DESC ") or           die(mysqli_error($conn));



 ?>

 <br>
    <h2>Database 3</h2>

 <table style="width: 100%">
             <tr>
             <td>ID</td>
             <td>??</td>
             <td>??</td>
             <td>??</td>
             <td>??</td>
             <td>??</td>


             </tr>
    <?php
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query103))           
         {


            // Here I try to find what database the customer is on
                $id2 = $row['ID'];

                if($row['ID'] == ''){

                    echo "intet id";
                }else {

                    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  `$v1`.`wpd2_posts` where ID = '$id2' ORDER BY id") or die(mysqli_error($conn));    

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == '') {

                                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  `$v2`.`wpd2_posts` where ID = '$id2' ORDER BY id") or die(mysqli_error($conn));    

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == '') {

                        }else{
                                $version = "coalsmil_wp111";

                            }

                        }else{
                                $version = "coalsmil_wp282";

                            }


                }

                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>". $row['ID']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>". $row['post_date']."</td>";
                 echo "<td>". $row['post_status']."</td>";

                            //And here I try to get the data out


                                      $querynavn = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT meta_value FROM  `$version`.`wpd2_postmeta` where meta_key='_shipping_first_name' and post_id='$id2' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($querynavn))        
                  {
              $fornavn = urldecode($row2['meta_value']);
                }
            echo "<td>". $fornavn."</td>";
                 echo "<td>".$version."</td>";
                 echo "<td>6</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";

         }


         ?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're connections are on the same database server you can specify the schema (database name) to select things from both over one connection. You do this by using `schema_name.table_name` instead of just the table's name.

So like:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.wpd2_posts WHERE ...
```

In your case you could use `UNION` to put it all together:

```
SELECT * FROM `schema1.wpd2_posts` 
   where post_status='wc-processing' or post_status='wc-completed'
    or post_status='wc-failed' UNION
SELECT * FROM `schema2.wpd2_posts` 
   where post_status='wc-processing' or post_status='wc-completed'
    or post_status='wc-failed' order by post_date DESC LIMIT 10
```

On a side note you could make this query a bit more readable by using the `IN()` clause for your critera:

```
WHERE post_status IN('wc-processing', 'wc-completed','wc-failed')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it give me this error. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: My bad. You should put the order by clause only once at the end.

Comment: I edited my answer. The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will be applied to the result so you want to `LIMIT 10` and it will blend between your two tables. If you explicitly want 5 from each table then `UNION` may not work and you'll still have to have two separate queries. (you can still do them over the single connection though)

Comment: Yes i now but now it say: Table 'xxx_wp282.schema1.wpd2_posts' doesn't exist

Comment: `schema1` is just what I was using as an example. If `xxx_w282` is the name of your schema then use `xxx_wp282.wpd2_posts`

Comment: where can i find the name of my schema?

Comment: I relly dont understand what i need to put in on where you have written schema1 and 2

Comment: They are stored in `$v1` and `$v2`. schema name = db name.

Comment: your schema name is the value of `$v1` and `$v2`. Also known as the database name

Comment: yes, thats what also what i think but i give me tis error now Table 'coalsmil_wp282.coalsmil_wp282.wpd2_posts' doesn't exist

Comment: Can it have anything to do with we drive $conn1?

Comment: Don't put the database name twice. It's `database.table` so `coalsmil_wp282.wpd2_posts`

Comment: it is prefixed so the $v1 and $v2 will take the database name automatically. Is there any other way i can make this work? Sorry for the many questions, i just hope to put an end on my problem. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're passing `$v1` and `$v2` to your connection. You could just use `$v1.wpd2_posts` and `$v2.wpd2_posts` in your query string. Just be careful that they are never set outside your program as that could cause a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: We have updated the code up in the question field - please take a look at it, and see if you get the same errors as we do and perhaps have a solution on this problem :)

Comment: Tank you et work well but, when i try to make take meta data inside the while row i can get the rigt data out, it mixes meta_value $ first name and sometimes duplicates them on the rows.